# Getting 405 error on API call -- routes set up wrong? (NextJS/Typescript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, next.js, axios

I am trying to use a custom email sign up form with the Beehiiv newsletter API.

Here are the API docs: https://developers.beehiiv.com/docs/v2/1f82a0eaf9b68-create

My web app is NextJS / Typescript -- the newer version that uses /src/ instead of /pages/

I have src/app/api/subscribe.js:

```
// /app/api/subscribe.js
import axios from "axios";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    try {
      const { email, firstName, lastName } = req.body;  // Assuming you're sending firstName and lastName from the client
      const postData = {
        email,
        reactivate_existing: false,  
        send_welcome_email: false,   
        utm_source: "WayneEnterprise",  
        utm_campaign: "fall_2022_promotion",  
        utm_medium: "organic",  
        referring_site: "www.wayneenterprise.com/blog",  
        custom_fields: [
          { name: "First Name", value: firstName },
          { name: "Last Name", value: lastName }
        ]
      };

      const response = await axios.post(
        "https://api.beehiiv.com/v2/publications/pub_abc/subscriptions",
        postData,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer xyz", // Replace with your actual API key
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );
      res.status(200).json(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(error.response ? error.response.status : 500).json({ message: error.message });
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader("Allow", ["POST"]);
    res.status(405).end(`Method ${req.method} Not Allowed`);
  }
}
```

I included all that filler to mirror a test cURL I got working from the API docs:

```
(base) reallymemorable@Christians-MacBook-Pro repo % curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.beehiiv.com/v2/publications/pub_abc/subscriptions \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer xyz' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
  "email": "jane.wayne@wayneenterprise.com",
  "reactivate_existing": false,
  "send_welcome_email": false,
  "utm_source": "WayneEnterprise",
  "utm_campaign": "fall_2022_promotion",
  "utm_medium": "organic",
  "referring_site": "www.wayneenterprise.com/blog",
  "custom_fields": [
    {
      "name": "First Name",
      "value": "Jane"
    },
    {
      "name": "Last Name",
      "value": "Wayne"
    }
  ]
}'
{"data":{"id":"sub_asdfgh","email":"jane.wayne@wayneenterprise.com","status":"validating","created":1704370796,"subscription_tier":"free","utm_source":"","utm_medium":"","utm_channel":"","utm_campaign":"","referring_site":"","referral_code":"3fS4ea7yg6","stripe_customer_id":"","custom_fields":[]}}%
```

Again, that cURL worked.

But when I submit the form on my live web app (or on localhost), I get a 405 error.

Here is the actual newsletter code in src/app/components/newsletter-form.tsx:

```
"use client";
import { EnvelopeIcon } from "@heroicons/react/20/solid";
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState } from "react";

interface SubmitProps {
  pending: boolean;
}

function Submit({ pending }: SubmitProps) {
  return (
    <button
      type="submit"
      className="button-primary hover:bg-black focus-visible:outline-primary my-2 w-full px-3.5 py-2.5 text-base font-semibold text-white shadow-sm focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2"

      disabled={pending}
    >
      {pending ? "Submitting..." : "Stay Informed"}
    </button>
  );
}

export default function NewsLetterForm() {
  const [pending, setPending] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const handleSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setPending(true);
    const email = (
      event.currentTarget.elements.namedItem("email") as HTMLInputElement
    ).value;

    try {
      const response = await axios.post("/api/subscribe", { email });
      console.log("Subscription successful:", response.data);
      // Handle successful subscription (e.g., show a message to the user)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Subscription error:", error);
      // Handle errors (e.g., show an error message to the user)
    } finally {
      setPending(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    
    <section className="border border-[#313233] p-0.5">
      <div className="p-2 border border-dashed border-gray-400">
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                  <div className="justify-between flex">
                    <div>
                  <span className=" small-header font-semibold">
                    Weekly Digest
                  </span>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                  <span className="text-xs"><a href="https://news.mynews.com/" target="_blank" className=" tertiary-link" rel="noopener noreferrer">Archive</a></span>
                  </div>
                  </div>


                  <div className="relative mt-2 shadow-sm">
                    <div className="pointer-events-none absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center pl-3">
                      <EnvelopeIcon
                        className="h-5 w-5 text-gray-400"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                      />
                    </div>
                    <input
                      type="email"
                      name="email"
                      id="email"
                      required
                      autoComplete="email"
                      className="block w-full border-0 py-1.5 pl-10 text-gray-900 ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-[#188F9B] sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
                      placeholder="you@email.com"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <Submit pending={pending} />
                </form>
              
              
    </div>

    </section>

    
  );
}
```

I suspect the issue is from `handleSubmit`, specifically:

```
const response = await axios.post("api/subscribe", { email });
```

I have also tried:

```
      
const response = await axios.post("app/api/subscribe", { email });
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Does anyone see it?

Comment: In your API code, you respond with code `405` in the case that `req.method` does not equal `POST`.  So try doing a `console.log("method is:", req.method)` at the very start of your API call to see what method is being sent.  [If I'm to wager a bet, I suspect you'll get the value of `post` and not `POST`....but I could be wrong].

Comment: @GregFenton - that didn't print anything in the logs, which leads me to believe the route is not being hit at all

Comment: That would be logged to your server logs, right?  What is your server (API) log showing when you make the API call?

Comment: it's not showing up in the logs for some reason. not sure what i'm doing wrong. this is hosted on Vercel if that info helps.

Comment: SOMETHING is showing up in your logs...or your UI is hitting an entirely different thing than you think it is.  Check out the NETWORK tab in your Dev Tools on the browser to see what the actual URL your page is going to when it calls the API.  Is it hitting the server you think it should be?

Comment: the 405 error shows up there. though what i do find interesting, is that when I look up the raw JSON request in the Network tab, it shows up as `{"email":"email@gmail.com"}`.  This makes me think that the code is not assembling the request correctly/fully.

Comment: Yes, the 405 is there.  But what is the requested URL?  Is it hitting the server you expect?  What is the posted data?  Is it the structure/values you expect?

Comment: it seems to be hitting `https://www.website.com/api/subscribe` -- should it be `https://www.website.com/app/api/subscribe`?

Re: the structure/values that I expect, it should look like the cURL request up in my original post. I tried to set up the API to duplicate that

Comment: I can't say what the URL should be.  You have that information.  But if it is hitting the wrong URL that would explain why your console.log() is not showing up on the server logs.  You want to adjust your URL configuration to be hitting the correct URL.

Comment: The URL depends on the directory structure. My api is in src/app/api/subscribe.js. I'm not sure if I need to include the /app/ part. I tried with it, and it also failed then.  It seems like the problem is elsewhere though -- it's not constructing the full JSON object.

Comment: You are on the right track, but we don't have enough details to help much further. We don't know your server configuration, your axios's base URL is, what the structure of the data being posted is (not sure what "the full JSON object" means), etc.

Comment: the "request payload" is recorded as `{"email":"levelchart8@gmail.com"}` in the console. But that does not match the correct payload outlined in my original post.

Comment: But that is what YOUR CODE is doing: `const response = await axios.post("/api/subscribe", { email });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using NextJS 13.4 or newer with the app router (as your path would suggest). The API routes are not defined the same way as thy were earlier. See https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers

You need to change the `src/app/api/subscribe.js` to `src/app/api/subscribe/route.js` if you want to keep the same URL. Then change the definition to something like:

```
export async function POST(request: Request) {
  try {
    const { email, firstName, lastName } = await request.json()
    const postData = {
        email,
        reactivate_existing: false,  
        send_welcome_email: false,   
        utm_source: "WayneEnterprise",  
        utm_campaign: "fall_2022_promotion",  
        utm_medium: "organic",  
        referring_site: "www.wayneenterprise.com/blog",  
        custom_fields: [
          { name: "First Name", value: firstName },
          { name: "Last Name", value: lastName }
        ]
      };

    const response = await axios.post(
        "https://api.beehiiv.com/v2/publications/pub_abc/subscriptions",
        postData,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer xyz", // Replace with your actual API key
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );
    return Response.json(response.data)
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: error.message }, { status: 500 })
  }
}
```

Comment: you are a gentleman and a scholar -- thank you that worked